# Java LibGDX how to check if sprite stands on specific tile e.g. door?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to change the map (method changeMapToWinter()) when sprite stands on specific tile of specific map. I have no layers on map.

Currently I do something like that if(sprite.getX() > 100 && sprite.getX() < 200 && sprite.getY() > 100 && sprite.getY() < 200) but of course it works only on one map and do not look too good and I guess there is a better solution for that.

```
    Texture img;
    TiledMap tiledMap;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    SpriteBatch sb;
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private TiledMapTileLayer tileLayer;
    private TiledMap winterMap;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, w, h);
        camera.update();
        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("untitled.tmx");
        winterMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("untitled2.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        sb = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bold_brown_blue-1.png"));
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    }

    void changeMapToWinter() {
        tiledMap.dispose();
        winterMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("untitled2.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(winterMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(sprite, (int) (Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth() / 2) - (sprite.getWidth()), (int) (Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight() / 2) - (sprite.getHeight() / 2));
        sb.end();

        Vector3 click = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)tiledMap.getLayers().get(0);

        // WANT TO CHANGE IT
        if(sprite.getX() > 100 && sprite.getX() < 200 && sprite.getY() > 100 && sprite.getY() < 200)
            changeMapToWinter();
    }
```

Comment: One way to change this code to be able to use it for more than one map would be to [add an object in your map](https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/manual/objects/) and use the position of this object for the coordinates instead of just hard-coding the coordinates of the door. [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/100715/143689) explains how you can get the object from the map in LibGDX.

Answer (score 0):

Solution you might use can be something like this:

```
Rectangle changePosition = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
if(sprite.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(changePosition)) ...
```

Constructor for rectangle have this format `Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height)`.

Also this will behave a bit differently from your code as you weren't taking into account size of the sprite, but this code does.

Btw LibGDX have usefull class for problems like this if you wouldn't be able to find appropriate function in [Rectangle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html) class or whatever shape you are using. It is called [Intersector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html).